# Populating a database in a Laravel migration file

Tags: php, laravel, migration, mysql-error-1146

I'm just learning Laravel, and have a working migration file creating a users table. I am trying to populate a user record as part of the migration:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function($table){

        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('email', 255);
        $table->string('password', 64);
        $table->boolean('verified');
        $table->string('token', 255);
        $table->timestamps();

        DB::table('users')->insert(
            array(
                'email' => `name@domain.example`,
                'verified' => true
            )
        );

    });
}
```

But I'm getting the following error when running `php artisan migrate`:

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'vantage.users' doesn't exist
```

This is obviously because Artisan hasn't yet created the table, but all the documentation seems to say that there is a way of using Fluent Query to populate data as part of a migration.

Anyone know how?

Comment: I'm wondering whether it is right to do so and why wouldn't someone use a Seeder instead..

Answer (score 300, accepted):

Don't put the DB::insert() inside of the Schema::create(), because the create method has to finish making the table before you can insert stuff. Try this instead:

```
public function up()
{
    // Create the table
    Schema::create('users', function($table){
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('email', 255);
        $table->string('password', 64);
        $table->boolean('verified');
        $table->string('token', 255);
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    // Insert some stuff
    DB::table('users')->insert(
        array(
            'email' => 'name@domain.example',
            'verified' => true
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: and how to insert multiple data ?

Comment: @SuperMario'sYoshi i think something like this `DB::table('users')->insert([
    ['email' => 'taylor@example.com', 'votes' => 0],
    ['email' => 'dayle@example.com', 'votes' => 0]
]);`

Answer (score 105):

I know this is an old post but since it comes up in a google search I thought I'd share some knowledge here. @erin-geyer pointed out that mixing migrations and seeders can create headaches and @justamartin countered that sometimes you want/need data to be populated as part of your deployment.

I'd go one step further and say that sometimes it is desirable to be able to roll out data changes consistently so that you can for example deploy to staging, see that all is well, and then deploy to production with confidence of the same results (and not have to remember to run some manual step).

However, there is still value in separating out the seed and the migration as those are two related but distinct concerns. Our team has compromised by creating migrations which call seeders. This looks like:

```
public function up()
{
    Artisan::call( 'db:seed', [
        '--class' => 'SomeSeeder',
        '--force' => true ]
    );
}
```

This allows you to execute a seed one time just like a migration. You can also implement logic that prevents or augments behavior. For example:

```
public function up()
{
    if ( SomeModel::count() < 10 )
    {
        Artisan::call( 'db:seed', [
            '--class' => 'SomeSeeder',
            '--force' => true ]
        );
    }
}
```

This would obviously conditionally execute your seeder if there are less than 10 SomeModels. This is useful if you want to include the seeder as a standard seeder that executed when you call `artisan db:seed` as well as when you migrate so that you don't "double up". You may also create a reverse seeder so that rollbacks works as expected, e.g.

```
public function down()
{
    Artisan::call( 'db:seed', [
        '--class' => 'ReverseSomeSeeder',
        '--force' => true ]
    );
}
```

The second parameter `--force` is required to enable to seeder to run in a production environment.

Comment: This is by far the best answer. Maintainable code that separates concerns!

Comment: I'd be careful to consider the long term implications of calling seeders from migration scripts. The migration scripts are date/time versioned, while seeders are typically not. During development, seeder needs often change, resulting in the possibility of versioned migration scripts running non-versioned seeders -- breaking idempotency. In other words, running the same set of migration scripts from day to day could yield different results.

Comment: It's been a while since I posted this and I wanted to provide our experience using this technique. Overall it has worked well for us and if I had to do it over again I would. That said there is one gotcha to be aware of. @originalbryan is exactly right and the consequence is that we occasionally run into situations where migrations break when spinning up a fresh DB because as the migrations run the seeder (and model) are more up-to-date than the database (since we may seed before the schema is fully updated). When that happens we update the old migration to address the issue.

Comment: @darrylkuhn I hear that it is not good practice to update old migration files - instead of updating old files, you should create new migration file - this is "workflow" for migration files by design

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski - using this pattern sometimes it is unavoidable. Imagine you have a migration that creates a table with two columns and then it calls a seeder using a model to populate the table. Then you create a new migration to add a third column and update the model. Now the seeder will run between the first and second migration and fill fatal error out because it's trying to insert records with three columns when only two exist (the second migration hasn't run yet). For this reason sometimes we have to update old migrations.

Comment: @darrylkuhn yes, your proposition break that rule. If we not call seeder inside migration file but put 'INSERT-s' directly in migration file then we have saved data consistency without changing old migration files. In fact i clearly not see problem with putting INSERT in migration files - e.g. i have system with 30 tables, and want add new feature which need new table with some initial data - so I put that initial data in migration file (in separate method) - no problem :P

Comment: I think its a good compromise to always add new seeders and version them e.g `20181215SomeSeeder ` and just make it a rule that seeders don't get updated just like migrations.

Comment: All of Laravel's language implies a seeder is for test data, so I think that should be kept in mind with design. It's important to distinguish between data that is part of the app vs test data, and including required data directly in a migration makes that distinction very clearly.

Comment: I agree with @originalbryan, and might suggest instead of mixing migrations and seeding, keep migrations for schema changes and have a single main seeder script that is always up to date with the latest schema and and ensures the data is seeded correctly. You can run this script conditionally during build.

Answer (score 19):

Here is a very good explanation of why using Laravel's Database Seeder is preferable to using Migrations: https://web.archive.org/web/20171018135835/http://laravelbook.com/laravel-database-seeding/

Although, following the instructions on the official documentation is a much better idea because the implementation described at the above link doesn't seem to work and is incomplete.  http://laravel.com/docs/migrations#database-seeding

Comment: I agree with you Erin. Don't mix migrations with seed data because it's highly likely that you would like to seed some data in your development environment but not in your production environment.

Comment: Good point, but there are some situations where some data must exist in production environment. For example, the very first default admin user must exist so the customer can log-in for the first time, some preset authorization roles must exist, some business-logic data also might be required immediately. Thus, I think mandatory data should be added to migrations (so that you can up/down also data records through separate migrations), but seeds can be left for development.

Comment: A small note; the link to database seeding is now: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/seeding

Comment: Please include the relevant part of the linked articles. [Link only answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged. Your first link is already dead and I had to bring it back from archive.org!

Answer (score 10):

If you are using Laravel 8 and would would like to initialize with **multiple** records you can do it in any of these two ways.

**1. The Not Recommended Way**

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->timestamps();
        });

        DB::table('categories')->insert(
            array(
                [
                    'name' => 'Category1',
                ],
                [
                    'name' => 'Category2',
                ],
                [
                    'name' => 'Category3',
                ],
            )
        );
    }
```

The above method is fine but will leave the **created_at** and **updated_at** columns blank.

**2. The recommended Way**

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->timestamps();
        });


        $data =  array(
            [
                'name' => 'Category1',
            ],
            [
                'name' => 'Category2',
            ],
            [
                'name' => 'Category3',
            ],
        );
        foreach ($data as $datum){
            $category = new Category(); //The Category is the model for your migration
            $category->name =$datum['name'];
            $category->save();
        }

    }
```

Comment: It won't work because the model does not exist at that time ... Never use model(s) in migrations as you may end up referring to a model that got removed at some point ... I am dealing these days with similar mistakes made by other developers.

Comment: I'd upvote @salih0vicX a dozen times if I could. Using *anything* Eloquent in migrations can cause significant issues later. Migrations function as a point-in-time whereas the code will always be "current". Incompatibilities are inevitable in any long-running project.

Answer (score 5):

This should do what you want.

```
public function up()
{
    DB::table('user')->insert(array('username'=>'dude', 'password'=>'z19pers!'));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another clean way to do it is to define a private method which create instance et persist concerned Model.

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('label', 256);
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();
    });

    $this->postCreate('admin', 'user');
}

private function postCreate(string ...$roles)  {
    foreach ($roles as $role) {
        $model = new Role();
        $model->setAttribute('label', $role);
        $model->save();
    }
}
```

With this solution, timestamps fields will be generated by Eloquent.

EDIT:
it's better to use seeder system to disctinct database structure generation and database population.

Comment: I like this one... it servers exactly what I needed to do, add a few user roles in by default on migration. Need to make sure to either import the model or refer directly to it `$model = new App\UserRoles();`, but other than that... perfect!

Answer (score 1):

I tried this DB insert method, but as it does not use the model, it ignored a sluggable trait I had on the model. So, given the Model for this table exists, as soon as its migrated, I figured the model would be available to use to insert data. And I came up with this:

```
public function up() {
        Schema::create('parent_categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('slug');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
        ParentCategory::create(
            [
                'id' => 1,
                'name' => 'Occasions',
            ],
        );
    }
```

This worked correctly, and also took into account the sluggable trait on my Model to automatically generate a slug for this entry, and uses the timestamps too.
NB. Adding the ID was no neccesary, however, I wanted specific IDs for my categories in this example.
Tested working on Laravel 5.8

Answer (score 0):

If you already have filled columns and have added new one or you want to fill out old column with new mock values , do this:

```
public function up()
{
    DB::table('foydabars')->update(
        array(
            'status' => '0'
        )
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By editing the first option from [Martin Mbae's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67354936/11759599), if you want the same result as the second option but not using the model, you can just do this:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    $sampleData = ['sample1', 'sample2', 'sample3'];
    $data = [];

    foreach ($sampleData as $sample) {
        $data[] = [
            'table_name' => $sample,
            'created_at' => now(),
            'updated_at' => now()
        ];
    }
    
    DB::table('categories')->insert($data);
}
```