# How to make Laravel installer

Tags: laravel

I just have a theme built with Laravel and I wonder if I decided to sell it how the client will install it and how he will migrate the database and insert the admin data?

I can do it by exporting and importing database from phpmyadmin but I think it's not the right way for clients.

How to deal with client?

Comment: depending on where the client will install Laravel app, You could make an artisan command for setting up your theme. Consider writing a documentation for your theme with all the instruction.

Comment: Do Not Pay Attention Just Want To Try It Myself

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to allow client to easily import your database, you can give a look to [Laravel Migration](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/migrations).

Also if you want to add some data you can give a look to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12736221/5018815).

Then the client will just need to do `php artisan migrate` from the root directory of the project.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ...  i'm asking how the client will install the project in shared host?

Comment: If the project is a full Laravel app you can put your code on github or something like that.
The client will just need to clone the repo. 
Also Ian Rodrigues give you a good solution with the packages.

Answer (score 1):

You can create migration using this command

The `--table` and `--create` options may also be used to indicate the name of the table and whether the migration will be creating a new table. These options simply pre-fill the generated migration stub file with the specified table:

```
php artisan make:migration create_users_table --create=users

php artisan make:migration add_votes_to_users_table --table=users
```

Now for inserting data you can use `Seeder`
To generate a seeder, execute the `make:seeder` Artisan command. All seeders generated by the framework will be placed in the `database/seeds` directory:

```
php artisan make:seeder UsersTableSeeder
```

**Client side**

Installation

- There are several ways of downloading the application:

Use GitHub: simply click the Clone or download button at the top right of this page and choose Download ZIP
Use Git: git clone https://github.com/austintoddj/canvas.git

- Run composer install from the command line in the project root.
- Run npm install from the command line in the project root if you installed any additional packages.
- Run php artisan migrate to install migrations
- php artisan db:seed to seed your tables

> Copy the contents of .env.example and create a new file called .env in
>   the project root. Set your application variables in the new file. Be
>   sure to keep the value of APP_ENV set to local for the duration of the
>   install.

Run php artisan canvas:install and follow the on-screen prompts.

Comment: i'm asking how the client will install the project in shared host?

Answer (score 1):

You could export it as [a package](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/packages), set up your `composer.json`, create a `YourPackageServiceProvider` to boot and register your pieces of code like migrations, views, routes, etc. You can though create a command like `php artisan your-package:install` that will wrap all of the steps to get the package installed properly.

So in order to get your package installed your client will:

Install the package via composer

```
composer require `your-namespace\your-package`
```

Register the Service Provider(in Laravel 5.5 you can use [auto-discovery](https://medium.com/@taylorotwell/package-auto-discovery-in-laravel-5-5-ea9e3ab20518)) and then:

```
php artisan your-package:install
```

You can look at [Voyager](https://github.com/the-control-group/voyager) as a good example.

Comment: i'm asking how the client will install the project in shared host?

Comment: Just via composer require `your-namespace\your-package`

Answer (score 1):

In my perspective client should not handle any code staff or command line commands, so what I'm doing in my projects is showing the user the installer pages :

```
1 - the first page is validate system configurations (PHP version, composer requirements, any more requirements...) and showing him what he needs to  have in his machine

2 - after the system requirement, I check if the database exists if I give the option to create it for him or if the client needs to give the name of the DB

3 - after that all the installations that will happen in the background
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to install external packages in any version of Laravel then you have to add the service provider to the config/app.php file in the providers array.
for example: if we install voyager package then we have to add TCG\Voyager\VoyagerServiceProvider::class, like this

```
'providers' => [
    // Laravel Framework Service Providers...
    //...

    // Package Service Providers
    TCG\Voyager\VoyagerServiceProvider::class,
    // ...

    // Application Service Providers
    // ...
],
```