# Should I normalize this DB?

Tags: php, sql, laravel, database-normalization

I'm building an API in laravel which allows people to create jobs to run on channels.

A channel might be AmazonUK, or AmazonDE, or Ebay.

And a job might be 'update_stock' or 'fetch_orders'

I'm going to have an AmazonUK class that implements the 'update_stock' and 'fetch_orders' functions, and an AmazonDE class that does that, and an Ebay class that does that.

And I'm going to store all these jobs in an SQL table. There will be a job id, channel, job_type, and various other columns that it needs to complete the job.

So my question is, because my channels are actually classes in the php, and my job_types are actually methods on those classes, should I normalize the above table, so that the 'channel' column is actually a 'channel_id', that matches against a 'channels' table where, say, id 1 maps to channel AmazonUK, and also have a job_types table where id 1 maps to 'update_stock'?

I've been reading a little bit about normalization, and found that the main benefit of normalization is NOT to reduce size, so I'm not 100% sure what benefit I would get from normalizing those columns, rather than just storing 'AmazonUK' as the channel and 'update_stock' as the job_type.

I'd love some advice.

Comment: If you already have a channel table with `AmazonUK` etc, which is referenced in other tables, then you should only have `channel_id` in your job table. If you then would rename one channel, you only need to do it in one place. Normalization is also about removing redundant data.

Comment: But the thing is that I don't have a channel table with AmazonUK in it. I'd be making it specifically for this use case, and it would always have to match a class that exists. So should I make the `channels` table for this, or should I just store the string 'AmazonUK' in the jobs table, with each job that needs to use that class? @MagnusEriksson

Comment: If there's going to be multiple jobs for each channel, I would still recommend having a `channels`-table for the same reasons I stated above. If the table will only contain one job per channel and you won't use channels for anything else in your application, then I guess you won't really gain much from normalizing it.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson what about the issue that, every time I add a new Channel class, I have to also remember to add a row to the Channels table, on both my dev server and the live server, or else it won't work? I feel like, in this instance, I might just be introducing a new point of failure...

Comment: As a counterargument to my above point, all I'd really have to do is make a migration following the advice here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12736120/populating-a-database-in-a-laravel-migration-file -- every time I add a channel, and remember to run `php artisan migrate` every time. It still adds a point of failure but at least it makes sense and allows me to code in what sort of entries those tables need.

Comment: "should I normalize" What exactly do you mean by "normalization'? Normalization does not involve replacing values by other values that are somehow more id-ish. But is that what you mean? Please give some actual design(s) to show exactly what you are talking about & so we can talk precisely about variants of it. (You don't give types for represnting "channels".) [ask] [help] [mre] PS "I'd love some advice." is not an on-topic question. PS PLease clarify via edits, not comments.

Comment: When this is clearer it will likely be a faq. Before considering posting please always google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags, & read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Decision between storing lookup table id's or pure data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383026/decision-between-storing-lookup-table-ids-or-pure-data)

Answer (score 0):

Definitely you should create descriptor tables.

Let's say you decide, that a better name, suits class, so you just rename in a table, instead of changing string your code in 10 different places.

Also you might want to show to user "Amazon UK", instead of AmazonUk, so you just add new db column.

If you use Laravel migrations, you can add inserts there too.